# Unexpected data from web scraper

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I'm scraping a webpage and the results are not turning out as expected. This is the code I'm running with Requests, BeautifulSoup, and Selenium.

```
#Beep beep so lets ride
driver = webdriver.Chrome('chromedriver.exe')
driver.get('https://www.cardkingdom.com/')
driver.maximize_window()

#Search card, grab URL
search = driver.find_element(By.ID,"tags")
search.send_keys('Silver Myr')
search.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)   
url = driver.current_url

#Making a soup
request = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(request.text, 'html.parser') 

#Parse for correct card
findset = soup.find_all(['input'])
print(findset)
```

I expect to be given several lines of HTML that contain info on different versions of the MTG card "Silver Myr." For ex)

```
<input type="hidden" name="category" value="Scars of Mirrodin">
<input type="hidden" name="price" value="0.35">
etcetcetc more of these
```

But instead I get something that looks like this:

```
<input name="md" type="hidden" value="RfORPzNURs_n059RoHnU2L51HXgZQBQvwGBvEn4MX4U-1647612983-0-AfhGlkGttGt49azWEYz9rEsee-yEC56PMZaCaTeA4vIEdChp-08thT9V2k_-2xor9a55ZZ1L1zRuGjBk9TZ-CzLuEGoPi7ExjndPPjhbmWoIFvKf_A695H-soqHzJsfeECscLD8XmtU5gcy1e6YQandkZqZtS_xeDqReorLLzJNBbU5az-QTuFIUnlHa8RjVOxixc8LObyob3bbBcktPf4Z00F_F2mPe8ZAjmjd8CLXitHZyKpjauOq4I8VnqTMl5qVKpcuc6RJzA0iAk-vHXQaDG2C4yiNWnEJybNSAtna2RZNXvwXU5OvEj2qBY_BKO47-j7QAauX1CYYCP_rrZ5U2mVaGZfpl9mPoTYV6tS_Z4Th7P8Y5h8LMhhMaPW3gw01YZBiHRbHaZRqyzC4Sr5qaw0ixtGGrqM-Z9pGhq60hagxyJ5MYmxVrLSfEG5Wmb9OSm05TUDRZ3ySltM2SXMF7JNUeRZokxFrdMO54KS0G7qjx3B6KiKIuJUqd1JFMOtBo264PylnfSU59u5iYq93AU9uz0AwMnEsPC0rKkheZ0NJq3y4-095oR_OvQzGiIwb3PZtvHvz2EHhRwJykWbTUziF2pNLfcZ8BcQx-H2LKsDfqVY4zpP53UGnc_mYMlFaE4vpOuySeVpkrKE1dE_uB9ANbDLpJ7vdyhr9bcghkTt1SNiBf1wfjN1G0WS1w168Z0fIBWk37TaObHhQ2YrNSi3RzXPs94I2isqQk06SrWDA2sAvpE3e6yBXuxhG0LoBM7isDwdWSP9L68KUv-8w"/>
```

Am I haunted, or is there a real world reason that this data appears obfuscated.

Comment: The page might be using javascript, which `requests` does not handle. Instead of using `requests.get` do `soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, 'html') `

Answer (score 0):

You can get this data without Selenium. It is in the static requests:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re
import pandas as pd

search = 'Silver Myr'


url = 'https://www.cardkingdom.com/catalog/search'
headers = {'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/96.0.4664.110 Safari/537.36'}
payload = {
    'search': 'header',
    'filter[name]': search}

response = requests.get(url, headers=headers, params=payload)
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'html.parser')
findset = soup.find_all('li', {'class':re.compile("^itemAddToCart")})

rows = []
for each in findset:
    row = {}
    inputs = each.find_all('input')
    for i in inputs:
        if 'class' in i.attrs.keys():
            row[i['class'][0]] = i['value']
        else:
            row[i['name']] = i['value']
            
    if i.find_next('span',{'class':'styleQty'}):
        qtyAvail = i.find_next('span',{'class':'styleQty'}).text
        row['qtyAvail'] = qtyAvail
            
    rows.append(row)
        
df = pd.DataFrame(rows)
```

**Output:**

```
print(df.to_string())
   product_id style qty maxQty                                category     model                                                name price        slug                                                                                       title variation qtyAvail
0      132098    NM   0     61                       Scars of Mirrodin  mtg_card                       Scars of Mirrodin: Silver Myr  0.35  silver-myr                                            Scars of Mirrodin: Scars of Mirrodin: Silver Myr                 20
1      132098    EX   0     58                       Scars of Mirrodin  mtg_card                       Scars of Mirrodin: Silver Myr  0.28  silver-myr                                            Scars of Mirrodin: Scars of Mirrodin: Silver Myr                  7
2      132098    VG   0      7                       Scars of Mirrodin  mtg_card                       Scars of Mirrodin: Silver Myr  0.25  silver-myr                                            Scars of Mirrodin: Scars of Mirrodin: Silver Myr                 20
3      132098     G          0                       Scars of Mirrodin  mtg_card                       Scars of Mirrodin: Silver Myr  0.18  silver-myr                                            Scars of Mirrodin: Scars of Mirrodin: Silver Myr                 20
4      257350    NM   0    243  Kamigawa: Neon Dynasty Commander Decks  mtg_card  Kamigawa: Neon Dynasty Commander Decks: Silver Myr  0.25  silver-myr  Kamigawa: Neon Dynasty Commander Decks: Kamigawa: Neon Dynasty Commander Decks: Silver Myr                 20
5      257350    EX          0  Kamigawa: Neon Dynasty Commander Decks  mtg_card  Kamigawa: Neon Dynasty Commander Decks: Silver Myr  0.20  silver-myr  Kamigawa: Neon Dynasty Commander Decks: Kamigawa: Neon Dynasty Commander Decks: Silver Myr                 20
6      257350    VG          0  Kamigawa: Neon Dynasty Commander Decks  mtg_card  Kamigawa: Neon Dynasty Commander Decks: Silver Myr  0.18  silver-myr  Kamigawa: Neon Dynasty Commander Decks: Kamigawa: Neon Dynasty Commander Decks: Silver Myr                 20
7      257350     G          0  Kamigawa: Neon Dynasty Commander Decks  mtg_card  Kamigawa: Neon Dynasty Commander Decks: Silver Myr  0.13  silver-myr  Kamigawa: Neon Dynasty Commander Decks: Kamigawa: Neon Dynasty Commander Decks: Silver Myr                 20
8       72240    NM          0                                Mirrodin  mtg_card                                Mirrodin: Silver Myr  0.39  silver-myr                                                              Mirrodin: Mirrodin: Silver Myr                 20
9       72240    EX   0     44                                Mirrodin  mtg_card                                Mirrodin: Silver Myr  0.31  silver-myr                                                              Mirrodin: Mirrodin: Silver Myr                 20
10      72240    VG   0     23                                Mirrodin  mtg_card                                Mirrodin: Silver Myr  0.27  silver-myr                                                              Mirrodin: Mirrodin: Silver Myr                  1
11      72240     G          0                                Mirrodin  mtg_card                                Mirrodin: Silver Myr  0.20  silver-myr                                                              Mirrodin: Mirrodin: Silver Myr                  1
12     127702    NM   0      1                              Planechase  mtg_card                              Planechase: Silver Myr  0.79  silver-myr                                                          Planechase: Planechase: Silver Myr                  7
13     127702    EX   0      7                              Planechase  mtg_card                              Planechase: Silver Myr  0.63  silver-myr                                                          Planechase: Planechase: Silver Myr                  1
14     127702    VG   0      1                              Planechase  mtg_card                              Planechase: Silver Myr  0.55  silver-myr                                                          Planechase: Planechase: Silver Myr                  1
15     127702     G          0                              Planechase  mtg_card                              Planechase: Silver Myr  0.40  silver-myr                                                          Planechase: Planechase: Silver Myr                  1
16     132036    NM   0      1        Duel Decks: Elspeth Vs. Tezzeret  mtg_card        Duel Decks: Elspeth Vs. Tezzeret: Silver Myr  0.69  silver-myr              Duel Decks: Elspeth Vs. Tezzeret: Duel Decks: Elspeth Vs. Tezzeret: Silver Myr                  9
17     132036    EX   0      9        Duel Decks: Elspeth Vs. Tezzeret  mtg_card        Duel Decks: Elspeth Vs. Tezzeret: Silver Myr  0.55  silver-myr              Duel Decks: Elspeth Vs. Tezzeret: Duel Decks: Elspeth Vs. Tezzeret: Silver Myr                  4
18     132036    VG   0      4        Duel Decks: Elspeth Vs. Tezzeret  mtg_card        Duel Decks: Elspeth Vs. Tezzeret: Silver Myr  0.48  silver-myr              Duel Decks: Elspeth Vs. Tezzeret: Duel Decks: Elspeth Vs. Tezzeret: Silver Myr                NaN
19     132036     G          0        Duel Decks: Elspeth Vs. Tezzeret  mtg_card        Duel Decks: Elspeth Vs. Tezzeret: Silver Myr  0.35  silver-myr              Duel Decks: Elspeth Vs. Tezzeret: Duel Decks: Elspeth Vs. Tezzeret: Silver Myr                NaN
```